# Check whether a date is missing or not in a list?

Tags: flutter, dart

So, i am storing all the dates in a list and i want to check how many dates are not present so i can get the ratio for attendance.

**My Code:-**

```
List<String> dates=[];//have some dates assigned to it

// now suppose user was absent on a date x and y then i want to calculate the attendance as:-
attendance=(present/total)*100;
```

Comment: You can simply use the list's length - `dates.length`

Comment: actually i am asking user to mark the attendance and then storing the days which he marked and suppose he forgot to mark then i need to check in the list that which dates are missing

Comment: I mean suppose you are calculating attendance percentage of month March. And in the particular month, user was absent for 2 days. Then `dates.length` will be 28 because the absence days will not be there inside `dates`, right? Then attendance will be `(dates.length/total)*100` where total will be 30.

Comment: ya but the thing is i dont know that user is absent on which dates so i need to find the missing dates in the list to know the count of absence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var firstDate=new DateTime(2021,01,04);
  var curDate=new DateTime.now();
  
  var days=curDate.difference(firstDate).inDays;
  print(days);
  
  List<String> allDates=List.generate(days,(index)=>firstDate.add(Duration(days:index)).toString().substring(0,10).replaceAll("-",".")).toList();
  


  List<String> userDates=[
    "2021.04.01",
    "2021.04.02",
    "2021.04.03",
    "2021.04.04",
    "2021.04.05",
    "2021.04.06",
  
  ];
  // non-user dates
  var      d=allDates.where((d)=>!userDates.contains(d)).toList();
  
 print(d);
  
 var attendance=(d.length/allDates.length)*100;
  print(attendance);
```

> Outputs: [2021.01.04, 2021.01.05, 2021.01.06, 2021.01.07, 2021.01.08,
> 2021.01.09, 2021.01.10, 2021.01.11, 2021.01.12, 2021.01.13, 2021.01.14, 2021.01.15, 2021.01.16, 2021.01.17, 2021.01.18, 2021.01.19, 2021.01.20, 2021.01.21, 2021.01.22, 2021.01.23, 2021.01.24, 2021.01.25, 2021.01.26, 2021.01.27, 2021.01.28, 2021.01.29, 2021.01.30, 2021.01.31, 2021.02.01, 2021.02.02, 2021.02.03, 2021.02.04, 2021.02.05, 2021.02.06, 2021.02.07, 2021.02.08, 2021.02.09, 2021.02.10, 2021.02.11, 2021.02.12, 2021.02.13, 2021.02.14, 2021.02.15, 2021.02.16, 2021.02.17, 2021.02.18, 2021.02.19, 2021.02.20, 2021.02.21, 2021.02.22, 2021.02.23, 2021.02.24, 2021.02.25, 2021.02.26, 2021.02.27, 2021.02.28, 2021.03.01, 2021.03.02, 2021.03.03, 2021.03.04, 2021.03.05, 2021.03.06, 2021.03.07, 2021.03.08, 2021.03.09, 2021.03.10, 2021.03.11, 2021.03.12, 2021.03.13, 2021.03.14, 2021.03.15, 2021.03.16, 2021.03.17, 2021.03.18, 2021.03.19, 2021.03.20, 2021.03.21, 2021.03.22, 2021.03.23, 2021.03.24, 2021.03.25, 2021.03.26, 2021.03.27, 2021.03.28, 2021.03.29, 2021.03.30, 2021.03.31, 2021.04.07, 2021.04.08]

Comment: but it would be hard to insert the date values in userDates can you add function to insert all the dates between the first date and current date like in your case between 01.04.2021 and today's date